# How to calculate Math.pow(10, n), with n>=10000

Tags: java

How to calculate Math.pow(10, n), with n>=10000.

My program alway print : `Infinity`, i think problem in the data type: `double`

Bellow is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double result = Math.pow(10, 10000);
    System.out.print(result);
}
```

Comment: The exponent for a double is about +- 1023, so "Infinity" is the correct answer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: @markspace That is the the binary exponent, the max decimal exponent is ~ +/- 308.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  It was way late, sorry for messing that up. @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try using [`BigDecimal#pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow(int)) instead, since `BigDecimal` has arbitrary length, only limited by memory:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10");
System.out.println(a.pow(10000).toString());
```

This prints out `1` followed by 10K zeroes.

Comment: 10^10000 can be done as `BigDecimal.TEN.pow(10000)`, and `BigDecimal.ONE.movePointRight(10000)`, and `new BigDecimal("1e10000")`. Although all 3 have the same *numeric* value (`compareTo` returns 0), the first two will print a `1` followed by 10000 zeroes, while the third will print `1e10000`, and is not `equals` to the first two. --- It can also be done as `BigInteger.TEN.pow(10000)`